# Solr segments.gen and segments_N file restore

Tags: solr, lucene

Unfortunately I ran full data import with checked clean index option. I was able to copy whole index to backup directory before they were deleted (I killed solr), but segments.gen and segments_N files were already updated, so any time I copy back index to its origin directory, all index files are deleted on startup of Solr.

I think it is deleted because segments files does not contain my index files information - because segment files point to "after clean" index files.

I tried to somehow reconstructed segments files, but was unlucky and I also did not find way how to do it with solr code change.

Is there any possibility to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it is unlikely that the segment_N and segments.gen files were the only things lost, by the sound of it, but you can try using [`CheckIndex`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html).

You can run it from a command line something like:

```
java -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex path/to/index -fix
```

Or you can invoke methods of it in your own implementation, something like:

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File("path/to/index"));
CheckIndex check = new CheckIndex(directory);
CheckIndex.Satus status = check.checkIndex();
check.fixIndex(status);
```

Comment: I tried index checker yesterday and it also crashes since segment fiels are missing. I know it is unlikely - but it happen - just run clean import and in time you realize that, index files are still there with original content, but segment files are changed and contains NO indexes, so if you start solr, it checkes these segments files, which does not point to indexes in directory, and all indexes are deleted, only segment files stays :(